# How to create data asset programatically (manually in python code) from data store uri in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-data-lake-gen2, azureml-python-sdk

I have connected my blob container of Azure Data lake as Data store in Azure ML studio, Also I am able to create a data asset from there on the screen - It reads all the files in different folder in to one file as well.
I want to perform the same action of creating a data asset programatically in python. I can copy the datastore URI after navigating to the data section but I am unable to create data asset in my notebook. I want to do it programatically so that I can read all the data in different folders and I can create it temporarily without registering it, after use I can delete it.

Ask: Create a data asset with python (no need to register it - I want to use it temporarily) similar to doing it in Azure ML GUI

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> Create a data asset with python (no need to register it - I want to use it temporarily) similar to doing it in Azure ML GUI

You can use the below code to create data assets using python sdk v2.

**Code:**

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Data
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient

subscription_id = "your subscription id"
resource_group = "Your resource grp"
workspace_name = "your workspace name"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ml_client = MLClient(
    credential,
    subscription_id=subscription_id,
    resource_group_name=resource_group,
    workspace_name=workspace_name,
)
my_path = "your datastore path"

my_data = Data(
    path=my_path,
    type=AssetTypes.URI_FILE,
    description="this is my first data asset",
    name="dataset1",
    version="1"
)

ml_client.data.create_or_update(my_data)

print("Data asset is created!!!")
```

**Output:**

```
Uploading sas.txt (< 1 MB): 100%|####################################################################| 522/522 [00:00<00:00, 2.08kB/s]


Data asset is created!!!
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[Create Azure Machine Learning datasets - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-create-register-datasets)